# Existence of RHS limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(t)=\{n(x+t)\}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. How to prove that $\lim \limits_{t\to 0+}f(t)$ exists?

If $x$ is rational then $x=\frac{p}{q}$ then for $n\equiv 0 \pmod q$ we have $\{n(x+t)\}=n(x+t)-\lfloor n(x+t)\rfloor =n(x+t)-\lfloor nx+nt\rfloor =nt-\lfloor nt\rfloor =\{nt\}$ since $nx\in \mathbb{Z}$.

We know that $\lim \limits_{t\to 0+}nt$ exists and $\lim \limits_{t\to 0+}\lfloor nt\rfloor $ also exists. Hence $\exists \lim \limits_{t\to 0+}\{n(x+t)\}$.

Comment: Thoughts please, if any.

Comment: What do the brackets stand for?

Comment: @Quintic, edited!

Comment: @Stef, it's fractional part!

Comment: I edited the last equality (right before "since $nx\in\mathbb Z$"), do you agree with the correction?

Answer (score 1):

You proved the limit for the specific case $nx\in\mathbb Z$, but I guess you could show it in general from a more general perspective.

- The function $g(t)=\{t\}$ is right-semicontinuous, that is, $\lim_{t\to t_0^+}g(t) = g(t_0)$;
- The function $h(t)=n(x+t)$ is clearly continuous and increasing (since $n\geq 0$);

putting all together you have that the composition $f(t)=g(h(t))$ is right-semicontinuous.
Notice that we don't even require $n\in\mathbb Z$, but simply $n\geq 0$.

I'll leave it to you to show that in general, if $h$ is (right-semi)continous at $t_0$ and increasing in a (right) neighbourhood of $t_0$, and $g$ is right-semicontinuous in a right neighbourhood $U=[h(t_0); h(t_0)+\varepsilon)$ of $h(t_0)$ and such that $g(h(t_0))\leq g(t)$ $\forall t\in U$, then the composition $g\circ h$ is right-semicontinuous at $t_0$.